# How to remove read-only in a new copy using Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, excel, spreadsheet, openxml-sdk

I have come across two spreadsheets giving me errors when using Open XML SDK to convert.

The cases are:

- Read-only password protection (I don't have password)
- Filesharing enabled (another user on the network has the spreadsheet open and spreadsheet is read-only until user closes spreadsheet)

If I use Excel Interop, it is possible to give parameters that will open a copy of the spreadsheet and enable write permissions and hence any programmatic conversion process can continue. This code enables the behaviour by utilising **IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended**

```
// Convert legacy Excel files to .xlsx Transitional using Microsoft Office Interop Excel
public bool Convert_Legacy_ExcelInterop(string input_filepath, string output_filepath)
{
    bool convert_success = false;

    // Open Excel
    Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application(); // Create Excel object instance
    app.DisplayAlerts = false; // Don't display any Excel prompts
    Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(input_filepath, ReadOnly: false, Password: "'", WriteResPassword: "'", IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended: true, Notify: false); // Create workbook instance

    // Save workbook as .xlsx Transitional and close Excel
    wb.SaveAs(output_filepath, 51);
    wb.Close();
    app.Quit();

    return convert_success = true;
}
```

How can I imitate the same behaviour using Open XML SDK?

Here's my code:

```
// Convert to .xlsx Transitional
public bool Convert_to_OOXML_Transitional(string input_filepath, string output_filepath)
{
    bool convert_success = false;

    // If write-protected or reserved by another user
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(input_filepath, false))
    {
        if (spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.WorkbookProtection != null || spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.FileSharing != null)
        {
            // Use Excel Interop to convert the spreadsheet
            Convert_Legacy_ExcelInterop(input_filepath, output_filepath);
            return convert_success = true;
            // REPLACE ABOVE CODE WITH SOMETHING NATIVE TO OPEN XML SDK

        }
    }

    // Convert spreadsheet
    byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(input_filepath);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
        using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
        {
            spreadsheet.ChangeDocumentType(SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(output_filepath, stream.ToArray());
    }

    // Repair spreadsheet
    Repair rep = new Repair();
    rep.Repair_OOXML(output_filepath);

    // Return success
    convert_success = true;
    return convert_success;
}
```